# Change ContextMenu iOS apperance (background & highlight color)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm working on my React-Native app and I use [RN ContextMenu iOS library](https://github.com/mpiannucci/react-native-context-menu-view) that was written on top of Native Context Menu component, everything works fine except background & highlight color behavior.

Looks like by default highlight & background color follows iOS theme, so it could be either black or white. Althought this behavior does not fit my app's colors and I wanna change it but I'm competely newbie in objective-c so I can't understand what part should I change.

Just to make it clear I make a little demo that shows ugly white highlight & bg color: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AASqQXXtRwE&feature=youtu.be

I belive that I should change something in this file -> https://github.com/mpiannucci/react-native-context-menu-view/blob/master/ios/ContextMenuView.m

Ideally, I would like to make bg color transparent, can you help me guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [contextMenuInteraction:previewForHighlightingMenuWithConfiguration:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteractiondelegate/3295939-contextmenuinteraction?language=objc) method. It allows to return a custom preview for the ContextMenu, including setting `UIPreviewParameters`, which includes `backgroundColor`, which should be set as transparent.

---

The main challenge is that it requires a view to display, but in `react-native-context-menu-view` we only have access to `UIContextMenuInteraction` at the time of interaction.

To fix that, we can create an `interaction -> view` map:

```objc
NSMapTable *interactionToViewMap = [NSMapTable weakToWeakObjectsMapTable];
```

Then, inside [ContextMenuView.m](https://github.com/mpiannucci/react-native-context-menu-view/blob/master/ios/ContextMenuView.m) in `insertReactSubview:` we remember the interaction-to-view association:

```objc
- (void)insertReactSubview:(UIView *)subview atIndex:(NSInteger)atIndex
{
  [super insertReactSubview:subview atIndex:atIndex];
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    UIContextMenuInteraction* contextInteraction = [[UIContextMenuInteraction alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    
    // Map interaction to its view, so that we can retrieve view by interaction later
    [interactionToViewMap setObject:subview forKey:contextInteraction]; // <-- new line

    [subview addInteraction:contextInteraction];
  }
}
```

And then add a method that will use the map to display a preview with transparent background:

```objc
- (nullable UITargetedPreview *)contextMenuInteraction:(UIContextMenuInteraction *)interaction previewForHighlightingMenuWithConfiguration:(UIContextMenuConfiguration *)configuration  API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){
  // Set background to transparent to avoid unnecessary highlighting.
  UIPreviewParameters *params = [UIPreviewParameters alloc];
  params.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  return [[UITargetedPreview alloc] initWithView:[interactionToViewMap objectForKey:interaction] parameters:params];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass "transparent" in previewBackgroundColor prop from JS and you won't get the white background.

```
previewBackgroundColor={'transparent'}
```